# Full text search query build

Tags: postgresql

Iam work on full text search build out.

Im having issue on how to check the 'not' condition.

Ex:

If the user give  giri and hari as search term ,then i build the search terms as giri & hari
and perform search.

If the user give giri not hari as search term ,then how should i build the search term.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [fine](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES) [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match both: giri & hari, match first not second: giri & !hari

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    to_tsvector(colname) @@ (to_tsquery('giri') && to_tsquery('!hari'));
```